# Развернуть spring-mvc приложение на tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

Создал проект и собрал его через gradle, получил `war`-ку.
Теперь нужно в директорию томката разместить эту `war`-ку.
Вопрос в том, куда ложить `web.xml,` и что помимо war-ки и `web.xml` нужно ложить в эту директорию?

Положил habr.war и web.xml в папку `/opt/tomcat/webapps/habr/WEB-INF/`

Запустил tomcat, но по пути http://localhost:8080/habr/hello не заработало.

Проект со следующей структурой:

```
src:
  main:
    java:
      mypackage:
        HelloController.java
web:
  WEB-INF:
    hello:
      hello.jsp
    web.xml
    applicationContext.xml
build.gradle
```

HelloController.java

```
package mypackage;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package = "mypackage" />

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
//also applies plugin: 'war'
//and this also applies plugin: 'java'

repositories{
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если устанавливаете web-приложение вручную, то просто копируйте war-файл в /opt/tomcat/webapps А дескриптор развёртывания (web.xml) должен быть упакован внутрь war-файла.

Comment: А куда тогда расположить в исходниках web.xml, чтобы он в архив упаковался?

Comment: web.xml должен быть в WEB-INF

Comment: Да, в моей структуре описано где лежит файл. Но в war-архив он все равно после сборки gradle build не попал

Comment: Как пишут в [документации](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/web_project_tutorial.html), каталог `web` должен называться `webapp` и быть дочерним для `src/main`.